# Specify hostname of service container on CLI?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

With docker-compose, I can specify the hostname for a service container.

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"
services:
  db:
    image: library/mysql:latest
  app:
    build: .
    hostname: my-hostname
```

Rather than define this in the compose file, can I pass it in as an option on the CLI, either during the `docker-compose build` or `docker-compose up` phase?

Comment: Have you tried with `--build-args` referenced in the manual: https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/build/ and https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/2111 ?

Comment: @b.enoit.be as far as i can tell, those end up as a `--build-arg` option to the `docker build` command, but setting the hostname for a docker container uses the `--hostname` option to the `docker run` command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`docker-compose` supports environment variables. So you can pass it using that

```
version: "3"
services:
  db:
    image: library/mysql:latest
  app:
    build: .
    hostname: ${APP_HOSTNAME}
```

Then use

```
APP_HOSTNAME=myapp docker-compose up
```

or

```
export APP_HOSTNAME=myapp
docker-compose up
```

**Edit-1**

If you want to use default values in environment that is also possible

> It is possible to provide inline default values using typical shell syntax:
>
> ${VARIABLE:-default} will evaluate to default if VARIABLE is unset or empty in the environment.
>   ${VARIABLE-default} will evaluate to default only if VARIABLE is unset in the environment

So you can updated your `docker-compose` to below and it will work in all terminals

```
version: "3"
services:
  db:
    image: library/mysql:latest
  app:
    build: .
    hostname: ${APP_HOSTNAME:-myapp}
```

Comment: this works! unfortunately, if you don't have the variable set, every single docker-compose command will throw warning messages. so if you run `APP_HOSTNAME=myapp docker-compose up` in one terminal window and then run `docker-compose ps` in another, it will print a warning that the variable is not set.